# Shall I define a function using declare built-in?

Tags: bash, terminal, declare

When listing all the defined functions on the system the name of each function is prepended with `declare -f`:

```
bash4.3 declare -F | head
declare -f __expand_tilde_by_ref
declare -f __get_cword_at_cursor_by_ref
declare -f __git_eread
...
```

As a proof of concept I am trying to define a function as:

```
bash4.3 declare -f 'count() { ls -1 | wc -l; } '
bash4.3 declare -F | grep -w count
bash4.3 count() { ls -1 | wc -l; }
bash4.3 declare -F | grep -w count
declare -f count
```

In the output above, only definition that is recognized when function defined without `declare`. Do I understand correct that `declare` built-in is not used for function declaration?

Comment: BTW, the "terminal" tag is for questions about *terminals*. For bash's purposes, the terminal is the thing that collects input for the shell, or displays the shell's output -- in a modern graphical system it's the program that displays the window with the text in it; in older systems, it was a physical piece of hardware with a keyboard and a screen (or, before glass TTYs were widely used, a keyboard and a printer).

Comment: But the shell itself is not part of the terminal, and the terminal is not part of the shell; the terminal tag should be used for questions about problems displaying text in a given color or font; or turning local echo on or off; or otherwise problems that relate to things the terminal is itself responsible for doing -- not with problems with the logic of the program whose output the terminal is responsible for displaying, when the problem doesn't relate to the display itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not legal. From https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare, under the table of error codes:

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Exit status | Reason                                     |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------+
| != 0        | Attempting to define a function using `-f` |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to clarify, why the functions listing displayed with declare -f prepended then?

Comment: If you use `declare -F`, they _aren't_. `declare -f` isn't ever expected to output something that can be sourced to redefine a function -- the body isn't there, after all.